# Disable Inline title in Django Admin?

Tags: python, django

How do I disable the title and caption of inline classes?

By default, when I add a record in the admin panel, Django displays the classes inline, title:
< h2>ClassName< /h2>
and a caption:
< h3>ClassName: # 1< /h3>.

I've tryed to put:

```
class ChoiceInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Choice
    verbose_name = ""
```

but it didn't work.

PS: I'm using the following versions: 
Python: 2.6.5 
Django: 1.6.5

Comment: You can override [this template](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.6.5/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/edit_inline/stacked.html#L8).

Comment: Thank you @AlbertTugushev... Anyway, I imagined that there was a property that we can set within the class.

Comment: As you can see in the template there is no such option.